# What is this pop up called and how to design this?

Tags: android, google-chrome, web

[pop up screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ALbc.jpg)The attached screenshot show the prompt to open the webpage in app or continue with the browser. What is this thing called ? Is there any design policy to follow? As I don't know what to call this i am unable to find it.

Comment: It is called BottomSheetDialogFragment

Comment: @ Usman Malik it is called bottom Sheet in android i think this tutorial may help full to you

Comment: https://blog.mindorks.com/android-bottomsheet-in-kotlin

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.